# standalone iMessage apps behave different in iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

I’m trying to create a standalone iMessage app. I had something that worked in iOS 10. I would be able to send a message and show a view controller when the recepient tapped on the message it would open the view controller for them. This same code behaves very different in iOS 12. When the user taps on the message he gets taken to the app store instead of the view controller.

I’ve been looking everywhere on information about this, but there seems to be nothing on this topic.

Does anybody know what changed or how can I dispay a view controller instead of the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem obvious but I suspect you've missed something in your testing.

The iMessage app will launch **if is installed** on the receiving phone. The installation test is based on the bundle ID so if you have mismatched that it won't detect your app.

When the app has not been installed, iMessage as of iOS 11 includes a link to take you to the store.

I'm working on a complex iMessage app and along the way created a bunch of small sample apps to test different points. I've just made the repo public if you want to check out some [im-plausibilities](https://github.com/AndyDentFree/im-plausibilities)